# Ajax in Laravel Blade

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I'm really new on implementing Ajax in Laravel Blades. I've been searching for tutorials and such but it's really confusing. I hope you'll be patient with me

So I have a blade that I want to apply Ajax with so it will refresh like maybe every second.

I wonder if it's advisable to apply Ajax on the whole page itself.

If not, here's the part of my blade that I want to apply Ajax with (it's in forelse);

```
<div class="row">
        @forelse($receipt_ids as $receipt_id)
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading text-center">
                        {{$receipt_id->receipt_id}}
                    </div>

                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <table class="table table-bordered table-responsive">
                            <thead>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>Quantity</th>
                            </thead>

                            <tbody>
                            @foreach($orders as $order)
                                @if($receipt_id->receipt_id == $order->receipt_id)
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>{{$order->item}}</td>
                                        <td>{{$order->qty}}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                @endif
                            @endforeach
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>

                    <div class="panel-footer clearfix">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success pull-right" style="margin-right: 10px;">
                            <i class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> Served
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        @empty

        @endforelse
    </div>
```

I have a feeling that the Ajax will be linked with time change or something.

EDIT: I kinda have a lead now. I used;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function()
    {
       alert('test');
    }, 2000)
});
</script>
```

Now my problem is what syntax can I do to refresh the page?

Answer (score 0):

Your question has a lot more to do with javascript than it does with blade syntax or Laravel.

Laravel uses blade to turn your server data (list of receipts in your case) in to HTML which is sent to the browser. From there, AJAX (communicating with the server from the browser) is done from the client with Javascript.

The current official way to do this using Laravel is to implement something using [Vue.js](https://vuejs.org/%20Vue.js), but if you have not yet then I suggest you simply use [jQuery](https://jquery.com/).

To call something every second in Javascript you can use:

```
setInterval(function() {
    ...
}, 1000);
```

Inside the function you can use jQuery's `$.get` to retrieve results and replace the contents of your list. The simplest way again would be to call an action which returns just the above rendered HTML.

I hope this gets you on your way.

Comment: Thank you for this! More or less I have a lead now, haha. I tried using that function and put an alert to test it. Now I'll try to use `$.get`. I edited my main post and my javascript is working now.